# Access @URL.action with Parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I want URL by **@URL.Action** with Parameter.
Here is my code but i am getting blank value from it.

**Script**

```
var OpenURL = ' @Url.Action("Document", "Controller", new { ID= "-22" })';
alert(OpenURL); // Value of this is coming blank
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Document(int? ID)
{
     return View();
}
```

**Route.cs**

```
 routes.MapRoute("Document", "OpenDocuments/{ID}", new { controller = "Controller", action = "Document", ID= UrlParameter.Optional });
```

please help me out!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

ControllerController.cs

```
public class ControllerController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Document(int? ID)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script>
    var OpenURL = ' @Url.Action("Document", "Controller", new { ID= "-22" })';
    alert(OpenURL); // Value of this is coming blank
</script>
```

Works in my case.